# lambda is giving Error: wbuffer_write: write failed unix error: No space left on device vips2png: unable to write to target target

Tags: aws-lambda, sharp

I am using Lamba to generate a thumbanil for image using sharp.
i have written following code.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const util = require("util");
const Sharp = require("sharp");
const fs=require("fs");
// get reference to S3 client
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: "AKIAU2UQ3GXUBWCGAIWB",
  secretAccessKey: "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"
});
async function resizeBMP(statusObj, params, destparams,width){
 
}
async function resize(statusObj, params, destparams,width) {
  try {
    // Download the image from the S3 source bucket.
    let orignImage = await s3.getObject(params).promise();

    // Use the sharp module to resize the image and save in a buffer.
    const buffer = await Sharp(orignImage.Body,{limitInputPixels:false}).resize(width).toBuffer();
    console.log("passed");
    Object.assign(destparams, { Body: buffer });
    // Upload the thumbnail image to the destination bucket
    const putResult = await s3.putObject(destparams).promise();
    console.log("passed");

    //fs.unlinkSync(temp_path);
    Object.assign(statusObj, { status: 2, previewUrl: destparams.Key });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(putResult));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Image resize failed due to", error);
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    util.inspect(event, { depth: 5 });
    // Read options from the event parameter.
    const body = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].body);
    const srcBucket = body.bucket;
    const srcKey = body.key;
    const dstBucket = srcBucket;
    const filePath = body.filePath;
    const extension = body.extension;
    const dstKey = `${filePath}resized${extension}`;
    const statusObj = {
      status: 3,
    };
    const width = 200;
    const params = {
      Bucket: srcBucket,
      Key: srcKey,
    };
    const destparams = {
      Bucket: dstBucket,
      Key: dstKey,
      ContentType: "image",
    };
     // resize image and upload it.
    if(extension.toUpperCase()=='.BMP')
    {
      await resizeBMP(statusObj, params, destparams,width);
    }
    else{
      await resize(statusObj, params, destparams,width);
    }
    console.log(
      "Successfully resized " +
        srcBucket +
        "/" +
        srcKey +
        " and uploaded to " +
        dstBucket +
        "/" +
        dstKey
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

But for images over 100 mb i get the following error:
Image resize failed due to [Error: wbuffer_write: write failed
unix error: No space left on device
vips2png: unable to write to target target
]

i have set the env variable VIPS_DISC_THRESHOLD=750mb
and memory is also around 2040 mb

Comment: What Lambda limits did you set? How much memory?
I can see you're saving the output to the buffer (directly into the memory). I believe switching the output to the file, saving it to `/tmp` should solve the problem

Comment: I have assigned 2040 mb memory to lambda. and i tired saving file to /tmp but it did not work out.

Comment: Are you able to see console.log(passed) message?